# Display the HTML5 controls only when played on iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, controls, show

I would like to know how to display the HTML5 audio controls just when the audio file is played on an iPad, iPhone etc...
I have no problem to use the preload feature on any pc or mac, but it does not work on a mobile device and need ato show the player just for iPad.
COuld you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the user agent (using Javascript) and check which device is trying to access your website.  You might want to go with a regex approach like this for checking (for example) if it's an iPad:

```
var ipadDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```

Then use that variable to show or not show the controls.

Comment: that sounds great and really thank you for your prompt reply, however I am so novice with coding, could you develop the part our to show controls for this specific device?

Comment: @jorgechele I think I could do that, but that wouldn't help you.  Don't you think? Try doing it and if you get stuck at some point the community will try to help you :)

Comment: very educationalist, I have to say, but I am afraid that after: if (isIpad) , I am lost!

Comment: I will tell you how I would do it, but you might want to program it. Once you know the device is an iPad add a class like "hideElement" to the HTML elements that you don't want to show. Then CSS will do the rest.